# PHP unlink() not working to delete files?

Tags: php, mysql

```
PHP unlink() not working to delete files
```

my code is deleting in database properly but cant deleted from file how pls help me how to delete data in my uploaded file?

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
include_once('db.php');
$objDbCon = new db_connect();
$strSQL   = "DELETE FROM study_material WHERE id='$id'";
$objQuery = $objDbCon->Query($strSQL);
unlink('../uploaded/');
if ($objQuery) {
    echo "Delete Sucessfully";
} else {enter code here
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: Give full path to your file in unlink() funciton.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really want to delete the entire directory, which does seem unnecessary, check out rmdir: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Comment: this question should not have mysql tag

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/projectname'.$filename);
```

where

```
$filename is ./folderuploads/filename.extension
```

Answer (score 1):

`unlink()` is used to delete files and you try to delete directory using this function (`'../uploaded/'` is directory not a file). If you want to remove empty directory you need to use [rmdir() function](http://php.net//manual/pl/function.rmdir.php) instead

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for unlink() function must be a filename rather than a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code:
1:- select file from your table.
2:- unlink file from directory
3:- last delete row from table
unlink('../uploaded/filename');
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make sure that the files/folders have the correct permissions also in addition to the other answers.

PHP *usually* runs as the user and so if you don't have the correct permissions to manage the file, you won't be able to do anything with it.

In SSH:

```
chown -R user:user /path/to/folder
```

This will set all of your files to the user PHP is using. Obviously replace `user:user` with `root:root` for example.